# How to solve this parse problem ? I get an error ''StoreSurvey' has fewer columns than were specified in the column list.'

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my parse code but I get an error

> 'StoreSurvey' has fewer columns than were specified in the column list

My code:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/adventure-works/StoreSurvey' AS XM)
    SELECT 
        SalesPersonID,
        StoreSurvey.AnnualSales.value('(XM:AnnualSales)', 'INT') AS AnnualSales,
        StoreSurvey.AnnualRevenue.value('(XM:AnnualRevenue)', 'INT') AS AnnualRevenue
    FROM 
        Sales.Store
    CROSS APPLY 
        Demographics.nodes('//XM:StoreSurvey') AS StoreSurvey (AnnualSales, AnnualRevenue)
```

Comment: Side points: a `DEFAULT` namespace would be easier as you don;t have to specify it on each node. Adding `/text()` to the `.value` path is faster as no node conversion is necessary

Comment: [dup on MS q&a](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/635008/how-to-solve-error-has-fewer-columns-than-were-spe.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is with the `.nodes()` call.

It returns a "pseudo" table of XML fragments, with just **one** column - the XML fragment for each match of your XPath expression. So your `CROSS APPLY`  should be:

```
CROSS APPLY 
    Demographics.nodes('//XM:StoreSurvey') AS StoreSurvey (XmlColumn)
```

where `StoreSurvey` is the "on-the-fly" pseudo table, and `XmlColumn` is the column of that pseudo table which contains the XML fragment for each XPath match (representing whatever the `<XM:StoreSurvey>` node in your complete XML represents).

In your `SELECT`, you then "grab into" the returned XML fragments to get the individual values with a `.value()` call:

```
SELECT 
    SalesPersonID,
    StoreSurvey.XmlColumn.value('(XM:AnnualSales)', 'INT') AS AnnualSales,
    StoreSurvey.XmlColumn.value('(XM:AnnualRevenue)', 'INT') AS AnnualRevenue
```